# Start Activity from different Application (APK)

Tags: android

I have Two Applications AppOne & AppTwo

App Two has activity as the following:

```
    <activity android:name=".AppTwoActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.myAction.TestAction"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

What I should do to lunch AppTwoActivity from AppOne (Different App)?

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Intent
            Intent intent  = new Intent();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below code to the manifest of your App One. Replace the name with your second apps package name.

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="second.app.package.name" />
</queries>
```

Then launch that activity using the code below. Or you can use @CommonsWare answer too.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();                 
intent.setClassName("second.app.package.name", "second.app.package.name.ActivityName");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `Intent` that will resolve to the other app's activity:

```java
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Intent
            Intent intent  = new Intent("com.myAction.TestAction");
            
            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e("AppOne", "Exception starting AppTwo", t);

                // TODO something to let the user know that the other app is not installed or we otherwise cannot start the activity
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: That did't work "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.myAction.TestAction }"
Please note that the activity I want to start is outside the application (Another APK)

Comment: @MindC3ll: Are you certain that your manifest XML snippet is correct?

Comment: Yes, Both AppOne and AppTwo Apks are build successfully.